# Repair Ubuntu after uninstall of libjpeg

Tags: apt, gnome, gui, restore

I had installed libjpeg9 manually at some point, because it was a dependency of some custom compiled project. I didn't need it anymore and wanted to remove it. I also saw some other libjpeg packages labeled with the "manual install" flag in apt and removed those as well. After that autoremove cleaned half of the installed packages and I have no more window manager / GUI. What packages do i need to install to get it back?

The command that triggered the disaster: `apt remove libjpeg-dev libjpeg9 libjpeg8 libjpeg-turbo8`

`/var/log/apt/history.log`: https://pastebin.com/Re75hFJi

Comment: You have the APT log, so you need to install again all packages that were autoremoved, as shown in the log.

Comment: @raj, which will unecessarily mark all of them as manually installed. I'd prefer to install the master package that in turn will reinstall all those packages automatically.

Comment: Essential system packages (like for example `libc`) that are installed when you install your system from DVD/USB **are** marked as manually installed. I see this on my system also and suppose that this is pretty normal in Ubuntu.

Comment: That makes sense, after all, all packages I removed were flagged manually installed as well. But wouldn't it still be cleaner to rely on dependency resolution as to have the packages set up in the proper order, etc.?

Comment: I have found here an information that you can install the `tasksel` utility and then tell it to install "Ubuntu desktop": https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-a-gui-on-ubuntu . Never had the opportunity to test it however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most convenient option to repair will be to reinstall the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop`, which will automatically reinstall all components deemed an essential part of the standard Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you are able to boot into the login screen, you can access a TTY by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (or F5 up to F9). Log in there, and execute the command.

If you cannot anymore boot into the login screen, you still can repair a system from a recovery root prompt with network access. To boot into a recovery prompt, boot into the Grub menu. There, select an entry ending on `(recovery mode)`.

This will boot you into a recovery menu:

[image]

Select the option "root". This drops you to a terminal where you can install "ubuntu-desktop" with the command

```
apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

(no need for `sudo` here, because you are at a root prompt)

After that, type `reboot` to reboot the computer. You now should be able to boot again into your desktop.

Comment: I did this straight from the cmd line and my desktop is back. I'll carefully check whatever else got removed.

Comment: You are right, as long as you have a terminal i will work without going through the recovery menu. I will update my answer. Sometimes, you may not be able to boot to the system, and then the recovery prompt is still there.